# What is another way to say "be who you really are?"

Tags: expressions, synonyms

I am needing a headline title for an article written about being yourself. I would like the title to be similar to "be who you really are." Or make that statement using different words if possible.

Comment: It's usually just *Be yourself*, or *Act naturally*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Another way to phrase it, especially if you are trying to strike up interest for the article.  "Be Yourself" is hackneyed, and will easily be ignored.

"Don't Be Who You Are Not"

Comment: Since you've edited your answer directly voicing comment on mine... I would add that "Don't Be Who You Are Not" is actually verbose and rather clumsy.

Answer (score 2):

## Be yourself

Works just fine, it's an idiom and well known, (unlike the more formal dictionary definition heading below):

**Be oneself**

> To be in one's most natural, comfortable, sincere, and ingenuous state
> of mind and being. You should always try to ***be yourself*** with
> those you care about. I told her to just be herself during the
> interview.
> ([Farlax - Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Be+Yourself))

Comment: Yes.  This is well known.  And would serve in a wonderful capacity to have readers of an article ignore it.  This is not good print.  This does not promote readership.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger This is not good print? We are discussing writing in 2017, not 1917 here.

Comment: Boring.  If you were working for my periodical I'd show you the door.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger: *Be yourself* is perfectly natural English. So far as I'm concerned, *This is not good print* isn't and never was (unless it's a highly localised  variant of *good **copy*** as used in the publishing industry).

Comment: 'Be Yourself' is something that would be in a list of suggestions, not a title of an article.  Yes, it is natural English.  But it is not eye-catching.  It in no way forces the reader to think.  It is overused to the highest degree.